# SQL Join doesn't show up correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

i'm trying to find a solution, i'm trying to get a data from different tables using same id. Here is my code

```
 "SELECT * FROM menucat LEFT JOIN vmenutab ON menucat.cat_id = vmenutab.menu_id";
```

I need to create sections, and fill them later with some content, table menucat is parent table with sections, vmenutab is child table with content.
But i have a problem, it doesn't show up correctly. It should be like this:

Section1

- Link1
- Link2

But it shows up like this:

Section1

- Link1

Section1

- Link2

I've been using search, GROUP BY and DISTINCT didn't worked.

tables:

menucat:
cat_id menu_cat_est menu_cat_ru menu_cat_en

vmenutab:
id (unique link id) menu_id (id to related section) menu_name_est menu_name_ru menu_name_en

menu_cat_xxx and menu_name_xxx are different languages data

PHP Code

```
<?php
$target = "SELECT * FROM menucat LEFT JOIN vmenutab ON menucat.cat_id = vmenutab.menu_id";



$mq     = mysql_query($target);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($mq)) {
    $menu_cat_est   = $row['menu_cat_est'];
    $menu_cat_ru    = $row['menu_cat_ru'];
    $menu_cat_en    = $row['menu_cat_en'];

    $menu_name_est   = $row['menu_name_est'];
    $menu_name_ru    = $row['menu_name_ru'];
    $menu_name_en    = $row['menu_name_en'];


    $cat_id         = $row['cat_id'];
    $id         = $row['id'];



    echo '<tr>
    <td>' . $menu_cat_est . ''.$menu_name_est.'</td>
    <td>' . $menu_cat_ru . ''.$menu_name_ru.'</td>
    <td>' . $menu_cat_en . ''.$menu_name_en.'</td>
    <td scope="col"><center><a href="content.php?veditcat=' . $cat_id . '"><img src="style/stylesheet/images/edit.png"></a></center></td>
    <td scope="col"><center><a href="content.php?vdelcat=' . $cat_id . '"><img src="style/stylesheet/images/delete.png"></a></center></td>
    <td scope="col"><center><a href="content.php?vadd=' . $cat_id . '">Добавить</a></center></td>
  </tr>';




}

?>
```

Sorry for my english. Best Regards.

EDIT: Added entire PHP Code.
EDIT #2: Added table rows.

Comment: what about inner join?

Comment: can you post your php code where you loop over your returned rows.

Comment: Hm in PHP you use FULL JOIN instead LEFT

Comment: if i replace LEFT JOIN with FULL JOIN, it show up an error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter

Comment: before i post my code what is `' . $menu_cat_xxx . ''.$menu_name_xxx.'` its a bit confusing. is `$menu_cat_xxx` sometimes blank

Comment: also your db data don't match your example at top

Comment: it's different languages data

Answer (score 0):

an example as i don't know your db data. also sort db by cat id

`' . $menu_cat_xxx . ''.$menu_name_xxx.'` its a bit confusing

```
$target = "SELECT * FROM menucat LEFT JOIN vmenutab ON menucat.cat_id = vmenutab.menu_id" order by menucat.cat_id;

$mq     = mysql_query($target);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($mq)) {
    $menu_cat_est   = $row['menu_cat_est'];
    $menu_cat_ru    = $row['menu_cat_ru'];
    $menu_cat_en    = $row['menu_cat_en'];

    $menu_name_est   = $row['menu_name_est'];
    $menu_name_ru    = $row['menu_name_ru'];
    $menu_name_en    = $row['menu_name_en'];

    $cat_id         = $row['cat_id'];
    $id         = $row['id'];



if(!$nocat[$cat_id]){ $nocat[$cat_id] = $cat_id; $section='<tr><td colspan="6"> section' . $cat_id . '</td></tr>
';}else{$section='';} // customise as i need sleep

echo $section.
'<tr>
<td>' . $menu_cat_est . ''.$menu_name_est.'</td>
<td>' . $menu_cat_ru . ''.$menu_name_ru.'</td>
<td>' . $menu_cat_en . ''.$menu_name_en.'</td>
<td scope="col"><center><a href="content.php?veditcat=' . $cat_id . '"><img src="style/stylesheet/images/edit.png"></a></center></td>
<td scope="col"><center><a href="content.php?vdelcat=' . $cat_id . '"><img src="style/stylesheet/images/delete.png"></a></center></td>
<td scope="col"><center><a href="content.php?vadd=' . $cat_id . '">Добавить</a></center></td>
```

';

}